# Node - post xml to server with request

Tags: node.js, request

I try to communicate with a REST api via xmls. I generate an xml and test it with [Restlet Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-rest-api-t/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) (a chrome extenson for testing REST APIs).
It works fine, I receive the response XML.
If I try to send with [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), I receive

```
 '<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Internal Server Error</body></html>'
```

in err.response.body.

The response from the API server is always XML, so I do not get why it is 'html'.

Here is the code

```
  options = {
    uri: uri,
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml ',
      'Accept'      : 'application/xml '
    },
    body: xml // I use the same xml in Restlet Client's body
  }
  rp.post(options).then(response=>{
    console.log('------SUCCESS-----')
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log('------ERROR-----')
    console.log(err.response)
  })
```

If you need any plus information, please let me know.

Comment: If you have control over the data structure for both, I recommend using `JSON` over XML for request and response data.

Comment: @Derek unfortunately it is a 3rd party server, and I dont have control over it.